# Write pug array in multiple lines

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I want to write my pug array in multiple lines like this:

```
- var data = [
  ["1", "1.1"], 
  "2"
]
```

but pug doesnt allow it. I have to write it inline like this atm:

```
- var data = [["1", "1.1"], "2"]
```

Any idea? Thanks for help.

Comment: Or how can I realise this? To work with an json object would be much more comfortable?
http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/#variables

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As suggested in https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/502#issuecomment-137893041

try this:

```
- 
  var data = [
    ["1", "1.1"], 
    "2"
  ]
```

Note that the `-` is on a separate line.

Comment: For all other readers: You can also realise this way JSON objects like this: https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/502#issuecomment-137893041
The separate line is just magic. (Y)

@Rahul Desai: Done. Thanks.